# combining and formatting dtypes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, jupyter-notebook

Working on a project where ultimately I want to try and predict NBA home game attendance. I've scraped my preliminary data, but still want to add other fields such as arena capacity, win streak and other fields I might find valuable.

In my initial dataframe I'm just not sure how to combine my date fields in a way that will make it easier to plot and work with later. Also any other input would be appreciated as far as other tips. Thanks.

[image: DF preview]]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a **[mcve]**. This means, no pictures, please. You can use `df.head().to_dict()` to paste dataframe data in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three *original* fields here: Date, Year, and Time.  (Weekday can be derived from these.)

One route would be to concatenate their string-forms and form a Series of datetimes:

```
>>> concat = df['Date'] + ' ' + df['Year'].astype(str) + ' ' + df['Time']
>>> df['Fulldate'] = pd.to_datetime(concat)

>>> df
  Weekday    Date  Year     Time            Fulldate
0     Tue  Oct 30  2012  7:00 pm 2012-10-30 19:00:00
1     Tue  Oct 30  2012  7:30 pm 2012-10-30 19:30:00
2     Tue  Oct 30  2012  7:00 pm 2012-10-30 19:00:00
3     Wed  Oct 31  2012  7:30 pm 2012-10-31 19:30:00
4     Wed  Oct 31  2012  8:00 pm 2012-10-31 20:00:00
```

From there, you're free to derive additional fields with the `.dt` accessor.  For instance:

```
>>> df.Fulldate.dt.month
0    10
1    10
2    10
3    10
4    10
Name: Fulldate, dtype: int64

>>> df.Fulldate.dt.weekday.isin((5, 6))  # weekend games
```

Here's a full list of datetime-like properties:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#datetimelike-properties

---

In the future, try to make your question a little more specific and post something people can easily reproduce, not pictures.